# Yii2 Active form dropdownlist with two fields

Tags: yii2

I want to create an Active form dropdownlist in Yii2:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'country_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Country::find()->where(['flag'=>1])->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'country'),['prompt'=>' Select Country']
    )->label(false)?>
```

The above example shows only country name. I want the country name with country code in the bracket. How can I do that?

Comment: you should change the query and add the selected column `code` using `Concat` with the country name and assign an alias to it, you should change the query to query builder rather than active record

Answer (score 3):

[`ArrayHelper::map()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper#map()-detail) accepts callbacks, so you can use closure to generate value for map:

```
$models = Country::find()->where(['flag'=>1])->asArray()->all();
$items = ArrayHelper::map($model, 'id', static function ($data) {
    return "{$data['country']} [{$data['code']}]";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add  a select method that return the concat string you need as name

```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'country_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Country::find()
        ->select(['id', 'concat(country, "(", id, ")" AS country ')])
        ->where(['flag'=>1])->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'country'),['prompt'=>' Select Country']
    )->label(false)?>
```